# Loop Through JSON array not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, loops

I am retrieving a json array of information using Youtube's api. I want to loop through the "items" array which is within the entire array to access each item's video ID.

```
results = {
"kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
"etag": "\"bvxF-DWHx1toJotsdJBeCm43SLs/Z5vAcycCC4VZd3cPfwzTWZ_FrUQ\"",
"nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
"pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1000000,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
},
"items": [
{
    "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "TvyWRevLG5I"
    }
},
{   
    "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "P8iKcdh5Ims"
    }
},
{
    "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "tiRZ7YQKUgQ"
    },
},
{
   "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "mENb0jX-SD8"
   }
},
{
   "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "B34hQieOXZs"
   }
}
]
}
```

This is my jquery code to loop through:

```
$.each(results.items, function(i, item) {
    alert(items[i].id.videoId);
});
```

I am getting the error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" for some reason. Also when I try getting the length (results.items.length)to use a normal forloop, I get the same error.

Comment: You must be using Ajax .please put your entire jqury function here

Comment: Works for me (after a small change)? http://jsfiddle.net/Nc8VS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix a little bit your each function, because you reference to wrong object:

```
$.each(results.items, function(i, item) {
    console.log(item.id.videoId);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8V2Hu/)